# FQL query SELECT user_id FROM like... returns empty array, no errors?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My script is working like a charm with **Graph API** using `api` method of PHP SDK. I can successfully create albums, upload photos impersonating pages where user is administrator.

I'd like to get `user_id` of people who likes my page. I found that this is not possibile using Graph API so i switched to **FQL** ending up with this:

```
// Use current page id to build query and get likes
$query  = sprintf('SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="%s"', $this->id);
$args   = array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $query);
$result = $this->sdk->api($args); // $this->sdk is Facebook configured SDK

var_dump($args, $this->sdk, $args);
```

Output is empty! **Is this a bug or my bad?** No errors, no warning no exceptions. Details (sensible data is shuffled) are here:

```
array
  'method' => string 'fql.query' (length=9)
  'query' => string 'SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="273552079362810"' (length=58)

object(Facebook)[3]
  protected 'appId' => string '292315032146649' (length=15)
  protected 'appSecret' => string '360abceefda40484db536cda4010813a' (length=32)
  protected 'user' => null
  protected 'signedRequest' => null
  protected 'state' => null
  protected 'accessToken' => string 'AAAEJ2ZBX4gBkBAOQvllIySNhlu6trtuZB5uCeWuxvBcnGvq3JBuy5FULZAObdgsHZBRiPgBCcqkFDjwzdaWi4B7MIKp5AZCzPenwxSIfAGgZDZD' (length=112)
  protected 'fileUploadSupport' => boolean true

array
  empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation for the like FQL table. `object_id: The object_id of a video, note, link, photo, or album.` Page is not on that list. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

"*I'd like to get user_id of people who likes my page.*"

You cannot do that for privacy reasons (google it), however the converse can be done. If you have a user id you can get their complete list of page likes.

Comment: First thank you for the answer. If you are an admin of a page you can create an event and invite people (using Facebook itself). Even if a page doesn't have friends you can select people from the create event page. I guess they are people liking the page, am i right? Well... you are saying that's not possible to get this list using API?

Comment: There is no way to get the list via the Graph API.  There's this way to get a list manually of the last 500 people https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=273552079362810, but Facebook might be shutting it down soon, so don't rely upon it.